# How do you call tasks conditionally in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

I am looping over a series of status tests running in Apache Airflow.  Under certain conditions I want to publish a message.  Something like this is what I have now:

```
 for count, test in enumerate(test_list):
        test = StatusTest(test['_id'],test['status'])
        check_status_task = PythonOperator(
                         task_id='run_status_checker_'+str(count),
                         python_callable=run_status_checker,
                         op_kwargs={'status_test':test},
                         provide_context=True,
                         xcom_push=True,
                         retries=0,
                         dag=dag)


        pub_results_task = PythonOperator(
            task_id='pub_results_' + str(count),
            python_callable=pub_result,
            #op_kwargs={'task_id':'run_status_checker_'+str(count)},
            provide_context=True,
            trigger_rule='all_done',
            dag=dag
        )
        check_status_task >> pub_results_task
```

Code that calls status checker, gets responses, etc:

```
    def run_status_test(ti, **kwargs):
        status_test_conn = MongoHook(conn_id='test_selector_mongo')
        status_test = kwargs.pop('status_test', None)
        is_up = check_test_status(status_test)
        status, response = is_up

        if status:
           if status_test.already_failed(test_conn):
               status_test.status = 'true'
               status_test.update_status(status_test_conn)
               message = {"Test {0} passed".format(status_test.uid)}
               ti.xcom_push(XCOM_CHECK_STATUS_KEY, message)
        else:
            if (test.already_down(test_conn) and 'false' in test.status):
                test.update_sty_down(status_test_conn, response=response)
            else:
                status_test.status = 'false'
                status_test.update_status(status_test_conn)
                message = {status_test.uid}
                ti.xcom_push(XCOM_CHECK_STATUS_KEY, message)
        status_test_con.close_conn()
```

Code that would do message publishing:

```
def pub_result(dag, ti,  **context):
    message = ti.xcom_pull(
        task_ids=context['task_id'],
        key=XCOM_CHECK_STATUS_KEY
    )

    message_con = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.URLParameters(os.getenv['BROKERURL']))
    channel = message_con.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='status_test', durable=True, auto_delete=False, exclusive=False)
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='outage', body=json.dumps(message), properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2))
    message_con.close()
```

How do I tell Airflow to only do the publishing part of the workflow if certain conditions are met such as:

- If there is a message then publish it (or run the publish task).
- If not don't do anything.

I was thinking I could just check the value in the XCOM and publish if there is something or do nothing if it is empty.  However, I wanted to see if there was a proper way to do it in Airflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the BranchPythonOperator to create a task that determines whether to call pub_result or some other DummyTask. Here is an [example](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_branch_operator.py) from the Airflow Github repo.